# webview date picker works in android emulator but not on device?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, datepicker, android-webview

I've used the code example posted here [calling date picker from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328117/display-android-datepicker-on-click-of-a-button-in-javascript/28792514#28792514) and this works fine in the android emulator. When I click on the date input box in web view, the android date picker appears and I can select it.

However, when I test this on my device, I just get a standard text input field it is as though the method is not being called. Does anyone have any suggestions? The full code I am using is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  public  WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "MyJavaScriptInterface");

    mWebView.loadUrl("http:// mywebsite.html");
}

    // Classe de prise en charge du java privé
    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        public String m_szTagId;

        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void openDatePickerDialog(String szTagId) {
            m_szTagId = szTagId;
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String szDate = String.format("%04d/%02d/%02d", year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
                    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity_RetDate(\"" + m_szTagId + "\", \"" + szDate + "\")");
                }
            }, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            dp.show();
        }

    } // Class MyJavaScriptInterface


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and the Javascript code is:

```js
// ---- date picker to call methods of the android device
$('#datepicker').click(function(e){
 getDataDate();
});

function getDataDate(){
    MSSAndroidFunction.openDatePickerDialog('datepicker');
}


function callFromActivity_RetDate(datepicker, data) {
    document.subHours.datepicker.value = data;
}
```

Comment: I added @JavascriptInterface above the method but still no joy

Comment: Just come back to this I have changed the code a little but the error i am getting is:


 [INFO:CONSOLE(161)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: MSSAndroidFunction is not defined", source: http://mywebsite(161)

I have changed the method to bind "MSSAndroid so i am a little lost

Answer (score 0):

You have named your JavaScript Interface as `MyJavaScriptInterface`, so you must call it from JavaScript.

I.e.:

Instead of `MSSAndroidFunction.openDatePickerDialog('datepicker')`, you must do `MyJavaScriptInterface.openDatePickerDialog('datepicker')`, in a JavaScript method.

I have a `WebView` based application, in which I define the Interface in another class, not an inner class, and in the initialization I do:

```
htmlInterface=new HTMLInterface(this, webView);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(htmlInterface, "Android");
```

Hope it helps you
Regards